# Grails field pattern for different time formats

Tags: grails, design-patterns, gsp

I'm trying to use patterns for my gsp file in Grails. I want to check if the time entered is in the correct format.
For example: 12.15 == 12:15 == 12,15 == 12-15 and so on.

```
<g:field type="text" name="startTime" class="date" pattern="\\$##:##"/>
<g:field type="text" name="endTime" class="date" pattern="[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}" />
```

That's my code. The patterns are just some trys.
Maybe someone knows a solution.

Greetings
Nik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
<g:textField name="startTime" class="date"
        value="${formatDate(format:'HH:mm',date:record.start)}" pattern="\\d{1,2}(:\\d{0,2})?" />
<g:textField name="endTime" class="date"
        value="${formatDate(format:'HH:mm',date:record.end)}" pattern="\\d{1,2}(:\\d{0,2})?"/>
```

I just skiped the part with different dots. Now it shows a warning if you use the wrong pattern.

Answer (score 1):

the `pattern` in your g:field tag will be pass into date template (for example: /_fields/date/_field.gsp) like you pass parameters into other templates. You can access it by `${pattern}`.

You can use any validator such as `bootstrap_validator` or `jquery_inputmask` to do the task