# Force decimal dot in g:field

Tags: grails, tags

I'm new with grails, I have a g:field for a price input, the problem is that the user can enter a number with comma, for example if user enter 4,23 it will be processed as 423. How can I force to the user enter a dot instead of comma? Or are there some way to convert the comma in the input number to a dot?

This is my grails tag:

```
<g:field type="number decimal" min="0" maxFractionDigits="2" roundingMode="HALF_DOWN" name="price" value="${fieldValue(bean: productoProveedorInstance, field: 'price')}" required=""/>
```

Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: some countries actually use commas instead of decimal points for numbers. however, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [g:formatNumber](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/formatNumber.html) instead:

```
<g:formatNumber number="${myNumber}" format="\\$###.##0" />
```

...or use pattern attribute for g:field. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525375/grails-field-pattern-for-different-time-formats) you can find an example for time format.

...or change *coma* for *dot* in selected field using javascript.

Comment: I solved this using pattern attribute with a regular expression: `pattern="[0-9]+(\\,[0-9][0-9]?)?"`, g:formatNumber don't aplpy for this case, thks for the advices

Comment: That tag `<g:formatNumber>` is for displaying numbers, not formatting fields.

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded using [g:formatNumber](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.5/ref/Tags/formatNumber.html).

```
<g:formatNumber number="${myNumber}" maxFractionDigits="10" locale="US" />
```

The locale US, forces gsp to use a decimal point.
Nevertheless, without maxFractionDigits, it shows a whole number.